# Rails Parameters aren't inserted into Queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I've searched all over for this similar problem, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Anyways, I have a problem with a Rails 4 application I've been working on. Until yesterday, it was working fine and all the queries to my sqlite database were working fine.  Something happened and all of a sudden no more records were found when I would load pages. I thought it was a database connection error and I checked the databases and I found everything was there. However I looked into the terminal for the server to see if I could see the query, and I found this was happening:

```
Badge Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "badges".* FROM "badges" INNER JOIN "badges_partners" ON "badges"."id" = "badges_partners"."badge_id" WHERE "badges_partners"."partner_id" = ?  [["partner_id", 1]]

Supplier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "suppliers".* FROM "suppliers" INNER JOIN "partners_suppliers" ON "suppliers"."id" = "partners_suppliers"."supplier_id" WHERE "partners_suppliers"."partner_id" = ?  [["partner_id", 1]]
```

It's not just these, but all my queries where the parameter is there, but the value is not being placed in the query. Did I accidentally mess with a file or something? It must be something small that I must have messed with, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is an unnamed parameter. Use indexed parameter:

```
[[1, 1]]
```

I'm not sure if index is 1-based. If it is 0-based, use:

```
[[0, 1]]
```

Comment: how would I go about changing this? the thing is, I don't know what happened to change ALL my queries from working and grabbing the parameter, to not working..